# Android - extend application or run main activity

Tags: android, state

I have an Android app. When I minimise the app I'm using the code below in the manifest to ensure that my MainActivity is always run when returning to the app (even when the app is pushed to the backgroud, say when a user hits the 'home' button).

The reasoning is that I perform some essential db lookups in the onResume() of my main activity which should gear where the user is directed/what they see.

```
<activity
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:name="com.mydomain.appname.MainActivity"...
```

Now, this doesn't seem to be 100% working as I mostly have to kill the process and re-open the app to gurantee the MainActivity is hit.

Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking of say extending the Application with a new class and having the work performed via the onResume (or whatever method you guys recommend) in that? Would that work.

Essentially, what I want is to always perform the task in question when a user returns to the app from a closed, minimised/in the background/non-foreground state. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your manifest folder in you activity declaration do the following :

```
<activity
        android:noHistory="false"
.....      
>
</activity>
```

this will assure that your activity will be called everytime you enter the application .

Hope that helps .

Comment: ah I see, so if i add that to the MainActivity <activity> in my manifest, it will always refresh no matter what state the app is in when returning to the foreground? - do I need the android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"?

Comment: i dont think you need clearTaskOnLaunch
try what i told you and give me feedback

Comment: excellent - that seems to have worked a treat. the problem was compounded by a ViewPager with an adapter I needed to refresh. All seems to be sorted now though so thank you.